# Disable all hints and suggestions in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to turn off a particular suggestion, or hint, or whatever MS calls it when I'm editing a python file.

If I'm typing 'None' into a file, a popup appears after the letter 'e' with a suggestion of 'NotImplemented'. Since I am a fast typist, invariably, I'll hit Enter which, rather than accepting my text and opening a new line, will replace None with the suggested NotImplemented. This means I have to stop typing, select the incorrect string and retype None, carefully remembering to add an additional space or hit escape. This has become very frustrating and a waste of time.

How do I completely remove this "feature" so I don't have to mess with it again? I've already disabled just about every editor.suggest and editor.parameterHint I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what settings you tried, but I went to `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Suggestions` and changed `Accept Suggestion On Enter` to `Off` and that turned this off for me.

[image: Visual help of correct setting]

Then to make the suggestions dropdown disappear completely, go to `Quick Suggestions` just below and set everything to `off`.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because it does stop replacing what I've typed with the suggestion after hitting Enter. However, it is still displaying the suggestion widget when I begin typing. I'd still like to have the entire suggestion thing totally and completely disabled.

Comment: Check my updated answer, you can also remove this in the settings

Comment: Looks like that has tamed the beast. Thanks so much.